# Ожидание перед действием Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. В рамках теста на странице сайта открывается изображение. Открывается - в смысле разворачивается и имеет на рамке кнопку `[close]`, либо закрывается после клика в не области изображения. И вот суть проблемы.

При развернутом изображении страница сайта неактивно, а анимация "закрытие" картинки занимается какое-то время. То есть по сути нажатие на `[close]` уже отработала, а работать дальше с сайтом еще нельзя и тест падает.

Сам я выкрутился их ситуации с помощью `Thread.sleep();` но понимаю что это не решение проблемы. Может кто подскажет что-то более элегантное?

Так же пробовал решить проблему так:

```
 public void waitForCloseImg(){            
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.()));
    }
```

Но какого события мне ждать?

Comment: Попробуйте так: wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibility_of_element_located(By.())) - ожидание пока элемент пропадёт со страницы

Comment: @blindeStern, большое спасибо, все отлично работает.  Но может быть Вы подскажете еще как дождаться загрузки этого элемента? 
Просто дело в том, что открывается изображение без изменения URLно, по xpatch его можно определить вот так:
`" href="/img/educ/card-maket-vert-17.jpg"`
А с самим изображением все немного сложнее. Оно разбито на три части(левая - предыдущее img, правая - след. и нижняя часть - [close] И у каждой части уникальный id

Comment: точно не скажу как это будет на java, но суть такова: ```try:
            wait.until(driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath').get_attribute('href'))
            print('first element done')
        except:
            print('some trouble in first element')``` Хотя, сложно так детально представить, что именно надо без живого примера перед глазами. Так что могу и ошибаться.

Comment: @ blindeStern 
http://pdd.by/educ/
В тексте есть ссылка `карточки активации Учебной программы`которая и открывает изображение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно думаете, лучшая практика в таких случаях - это явные ожидания. Для попап элементов лучше использовать состояния, связанные с видимостью или кликабельностью элементов. Не достаточно просто проверить, что элемент есть или нет в DOM, так как он может быть невидимым. Изучите модуль ExpectedConditions, думаю найдете там много полезных классов.

Для ожидания появления и исчезания всплывающего окна используем соответственно:

```
ExpectedCondition.visibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)
ExpectedCondition.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By locator)
```

Что касается ожидания именно загрузки изображения, то нужна ли вам фактическая загрузка? На тесты же никто смотреть не будет, т.е. можно просто проверить, что  появился элемент img с правильным атрибутом scr (или другой элемент с правильным классом, если картинка идет как бэкграунд)